# Overwriting data of similar length in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Lets say I have a df like this:
[image]

I want to take the data in w at the day before and put it in w the day after.
So just want to overwrite the data on w 1929-02-02 with the data on w from 1929-02-01. All the other columns should be as is. They are similar length!

I have tried something like this, but it just puts in nan.
[image]

[image]
it is pretty much like saying. B on row 3 and 4 is equal to B on row 1 and 2

This code can be used for testing. Just want all values of w at first date, to overwrite all values of w at second date. The counter is used because this is just a simplification of the problem in a loop.

```
  a = {'PERMNO' : pd.Series(["10006","10007", "10008", "10006","10007", "10008"], index=['1929-02-01', '1929-02-01', '1929-02-01','1929-02-02', '1929-02-02', '1929-02-02']), 
   'w' : pd.Series([0.25, 0.5, 0.25, 0.33,0.33,0.33], index=['1929-02-01', '1929-02-01', '1929-02-01','1929-02-02', '1929-02-02', '1929-02-02']),'counter' : pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4,5,6], index=['1929-02-01', '1929-02-01', '1929-02-01','1929-02-02', '1929-02-02', '1929-02-02'])}
df= pd.DataFrame(a)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Please show the data as copyable **text**. We need to be able to reproduce with your data to test possible solutions.

Comment: I am a bit unsure how to do that. Quite large dataframe, so not that easy to just copy. It think the problem is pretty simple, but I just cant manage it.

Comment: I do not need the full dataframe! Just enough data to reproduce (normally more of less 10  rows should be enough...). And the code should also be presented as copyable text.

Comment: Okay! I will try

Comment: a = {'PERMNO' : pd.Series(["10006","10007", "10008", "10006","10007", "10008"], index=['1929-02-01', '1929-02-01', '1929-02-01','1929-02-02', '1929-02-02', '1929-02-02']), 
   'w' : pd.Series([0.25, 0.5, 0.25, 0.33,0.33,0.33], index=['1929-02-01', '1929-02-01', '1929-02-01','1929-02-02', '1929-02-02', '1929-02-02'])}
df= pd.DataFrame(a)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

Comment: Something like this then? Should give dataframe where what is needed is to copy the values at w at first date, and overwrite the w at the second date with that data

Comment: @felthefel Instead of writing it in a comment, you can go back and *edit* your question to provide more details.  Please also put your code as *text* instead of an image.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/243292

Comment: Done! :) should be updated now

Comment: Can we rely on PERMNO values to be consistent across days and assign the value of same PERMNO on previous day?

Comment: Yes! They should all allign and be the same! 

The real problem is to make it loop go through the whole dataset and do this, while starting over at the beginning of each month. 

Take the weights at the first date of the month and move it down to the next date. Then these weights are multiplied with (1+r) and then moved to the next date again. This is done for a month,  then it starts over again by taking the first date in the month and moving it to the next, multiply with (1+r)...... and so on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.loc` for indexing the dataframe as the error message suggests.

```py
data.loc[(data["counter"] < 901) & (data["counter"] >= 451), "w"] = change0["w"]
```

Comment: Try `change0["w"].values` instead of `change0["w"]`